# TypeError when using ScipyOptimizerInterface in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use the ScipyOptimizerInterface to optimize some functions. I tried to run the following code snippet (slightly modified from the tensorflow document) to get some ideas on how it works.

```
vector = tf.Variable([7., 7.], 'vector')
# Make vector norm as small as possible.
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(vector))

optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss, options={'maxiter': 100})

with tf.Session() as session:
    optimizer.minimize(session)
# The value of vector should now be [0., 0.].
```

I however got the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-e81545f4bb15> in <module>()
      4 loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(vector))
      5 
----> 6 optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss, options={'maxiter': 100})
      7 
      8 with tf.Session() as session:

/s/anaconda/....../miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/opt/python/training/external_optimizer.pyc in __init__(self, loss, var_list, equalities, inequalities, var_to_bounds, **optimizer_kwargs)
    124     self.optimizer_kwargs = optimizer_kwargs
    125 
--> 126     self._packed_var = self._pack(self._vars)
    127     self._packed_loss_grad = self._pack(loss_grads)
    128     self._packed_equality_grads = [

/s/anaconda/...../miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/opt/python/training/external_optimizer.pyc in _pack(cls, tensors)
    257     else:
    258       flattened = [array_ops.reshape(tensor, [-1]) for tensor in tensors]
--> 259       return array_ops.concat(flattened, 0)
    260 
    261   def _make_eval_func(self, tensors, session, feed_dict, fetches,

/s/anaconda/...../miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.pyc in concat(values, axis, name)
   1064   return gen_array_ops._concat_v2(values=values,
   1065                                   axis=axis,
-> 1066                                   name=name)
   1067 
   1068 

/s/anaconda/...../miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.pyc in _concat_v2(values, axis, name)
    493   """
    494   result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("ConcatV2", values=values, axis=axis,
--> 495                                 name=name)
    496   return result
    497 

/s/anaconda/...../miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.pyc in apply_op(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    461                                 (prefix, dtype.name))
    462               else:
--> 463                 raise TypeError("%s that don't all match." % prefix)
    464             else:
    465               raise TypeError("%s that are invalid." % prefix)

TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [float64, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float64, float64, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float32, float64, float32, float32] that don't all match.
```

I am using tensorflow 1.3.0-rc0 and python 2.7.12 from Continuum Analytics. Could you please tell how to fix this problem and prevent it from happening later?

Comment: The error seems pretty clear, you are passing a list of tensors with mismatched types. You probably need to find some way to cast your loss object to a list of all Float64 (to preserve full precision).

Comment: Hi csunday 95! Thanks for your comment! I indeed had tried to cast the cost using: loss = tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(vector)), dtype=tf.float32) but 
the compiler still complained that the first argument and two others in the initilization of optimizer are float64!

Answer (score 0):

The following code works on tensorflow version `1.2.0`. You also need to initialize the variables.

```
import tensorflow as tf
vector = tf.Variable([7., 7.], 'vector')
# Make vector norm as small as possible.
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(vector))


optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(
    loss, options={'maxiter': 100})

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(session.run(vector))  # results: [7.0, 7.0]
    optimizer.minimize(session)
    print(session.run(vector))  # results: [ -1.88996808e-06  -1.88996808e-06]
```

Comment: Hi Ishant Mrinal! Thank you so much for your quick response! I tried to run your code but got the same error. It seems to me that the compiler is very picky and it raises the error when initilizing the optimizer. By the way, I am running the code on a jupyter notebook.

Comment: the issue maybe then related to your tensorflow version or jupyter.

Comment: Thanks Ishant! I will check those two things you mentioned.